# For the first time - the first time

Tags: grammar

I would like to know the difference between "For the first time - the first time". It seems to me that sometimes they are interchangeable but at other times they are not.

For example: (not interchangeable)

**1) Most animals can swim right away the first time they go into water.**

**2) Most animals can swim right away for the first time they go into water.** (seems like they might not be able to swim the second time)

For example: (interchangeable)

**3) They met for the first time in 1980.**

**4) The first time they met was in 1980.**

**Plus here is an explanation by a Londoner**

*|No, they mean different things and have different grammar. 'For the first time' is a complete description of a time, and it implies other times that came before it.

For the first time, he won a prize. [He had never won a prize before this. This was his first time to win a prize. But he might have tried many times before.]

'The first time' needs to be followed by a relative clause saying what is 'first' about it. Then, including the relative clause, it forms a complete description of a time. It also implies there were not other times before this - this one is the first.

The first time (that) he took part in the competition, he won a prize. [He had never taken part in the competition before this. And when finally he did take part, he won.] |*

Is the explanation correct? I have made up two sentence to test the explanation. Would it be correct to say that in 5 it is necessary to understand that I had been trying to win a prize before yesterday?

**5) Yesterday I won a prize for the first time.**

**6) The first time I won a prize was yesterday.**

Comment: "Yesterday I won a prize for the first time." does not necessarily imply that you had been trying to win a prize before yesterday. If it's important you'd make it explicit, e.g. "Yesterday, after many prior losses, I finally won a prize.", or, "I never won a prize until yesterday."

Comment: #2 sounds mildly incorrect to me.

Comment: They're not interchangeable if you have to change the order. You're really talking about completely different constructions. This is like the difference between "I gave Bob a drink" vs "I gave a drink *to* Bob". You can't say "I gave Bob to a drink" or "I gave a drink Bob".

Comment: I am not sure that your comparison is useful. The question wants a relevant answer not just a comparison with a foreign construction.

Answer (score 3):

> 1: Yesterday I went to Ascot, and I bet on several races. I couldn't believe it when I actually *won*...
>
> 1a: ...for the first time
> 1b: ...the first time

Clearly there's a difference in *that* example. #1 means I'd never won (a bet at Ascot) before yesterday (when any or all of my bets might have won). But #2 means I won the first bet I placed yesterday (I may or may not have won bets before yesterday - that's unspecified).

In general, *"**for** the first time"* implies *"first time **ever**"*, whereas plain *"**the** first time"* usually implies *the first of the contextually relevant instances/times* (in my example, yesterday's bets).

Comment: Any comment on my examples? Namely 1,2, 5,6

Comment: Ex #2 is not a valid construction. I'm not sure how to specify the "grammatical rule" it violates (though I'm sure there is one). Note that ***right away*** is syntactically irrelevant to the issue;  simplifying some other elements, we get *"Cats can swim the first time they try"*. It may then help to consider replacing *the first time* with *when* - if you include ***for*** you end up with gibberish: *"Cats can swim **for when** they try"*. Apart from your #2 (and the distinction in my answer), there's nothing unusual about any of your other examples.

Comment: Do you mean that the rest of the examples are OK? Do the alike sentences mean the same? I am trying to find out when For the first time - the first time can be interchangeable.

Comment: Another question. Do you take this sentence "Yesterday I went to Ascot, and I bet on several races. I couldn't believe it when I actually won for the first time" to mean that the person had been trying to win before that time or not necessarily?

Comment: @user1425: Pragmatically, in your exact context it's likely the speaker had previously tried to win unsuccessfully, but I don't think that's particularly implied by ***for the first time*** (note that both ***couldn't believe it*** and ***actually*** each strongly invite such an interpretation anyway). If someone said *"I had sex for the first time on my 18th birthday"*, that in no way implies they'd spent years before that desperately seeking sex (they *might* have, but that's a matter of adolescent sexual proclivities, not language use! :)